# How to use execut in vim indentexpr

Tags: vim

I tried to use execut in vim indentexpr with under code

```
function! AddSpace(lnum,str)
    while len(getline(a:lnum)) < 80
        execut a:lnum . "," . a:lnum . "s/".a:str."/ ".a:str
    endwhile
endfunction

function! GetIndent()
    if getline(v:lnum) =~ ';'
        call AddSpace(v:lnum,";")
    endif     
    ...
    return ...
endfunction

setlocal indentexpr=GetIndent()
```

and gg=G.It doesn't work...
Vim just fail into a dead loop...
However,other indent rules works before the loop.

But hen I call it by

```
call AddSpace(3,";")
```

It works fine.

Maybe "execut" dosen't work in indentexpr?

Is there still any way to insert space into the file with "execut"?
Or is there better way to finish the insert without cursor moving?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you are so desperate to shorten `execute`, why don't you shorten it to `exe`?

Comment: exe sounds like something from microsoft...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'indentexpr'` is not meant to actually modify the text directly. In fact, it is explicitly forbidden to modify the text while evaluating the expression. Error messages are suppressed by default, so you don't get an indication something is wrong, but the expression just stops when it encounters the text modification.

Your AddSpace function should return the number of spaces to add, rather than actually adding the spaces. Note you don't need the while loop, you can just use subtraction to find the number of spaces needed.

See `:help 'indentexpr'` for details.

Comment: What if I want to get `console.log(a)                    ;` when indent `console.log(a);`?I can only source another script?

Comment: Indentation only affects whitespace at the beginning of the line. If you want to affect the entire line you'll need a custom mapping, or possibly a formatexpr.